# What's the differences between different types of utf-8?

Tags: linux, fonts, utf-8, charset

There is a problem with skype on linux.  If I change my locale setting to en_US.utf-8, Chinese characters are poorly rendered (some are bold, some are not).  If I change my locale setting to zh_CN.utf-8, both English and Chinese are rendered properly.  Font settings are the same.

**Here is my questions:**
Q1: What's the differences between different types of UTF-8 charset in linux locale setting?
Q2: How can it affect the display of certain language?

Comment: I've gotten the feeling that there *is* something, but as a monolinguistic English speaker, I can only go so far as to say I'm pretty sure you're on to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: What's the differences between different types of UTF-8 charset in linux locale setting?

Absolutely none. The difference is not caused by the charset.

> Q2: How can it affect the display of certain language?

*Fontconfig,* the Linux fonts configuration system, uses your system locale's "language" and "territory" as a hint when choosing the best font for a particular character. (For example, on my system, it picks either "IPAMincho" or "Source Han Sans" depending on the locale. I think it doesn't help that the former is actually tagged with "lang=en" in its own metadata despite not being made for English text.)

AFAIK, this is necessary because the glyphs themselves don't provide enough information about which language they're in, and (due to Unicode's "Han Unification") can provide different renderings for the same glyph.

You can set the `FC_LANG="zh_CN"` environment variable to provide a different locale hint specifically for Fontconfig without changing the global locale.

You can also set `LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"` for the same effect; this might fit better into the system's locale configuration files. (Normally the language_territory part of $LC_CTYPE isn't used for anything, so fontconfig repurposes it.)